# Nodemon + Socket.io

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, create-react-app, nodemon

I'm working on Create React App with a node backend that uses sockets for parts of its features. I have the following issue. Whenever I hit `command` + `s` nodemon restarts the dev server and the socket connection throws a Proxy Error `Proxy error: Could not proxy request`. A hard refresh allows me to continue to dev however the soft restart by nodemon seems to be causing this issue. How can I configure socket.io to work with the nodemon restarts?

1. I've double checked my proxy in the package.json of the react client to point to port of the API
2. I've dabbled with the socket.io options to get this resolved